# Solver "minimum number of cells"

Tags: excel, solver, portfolio

I am using Solver in excel to solve optimal portfolio weights, but there is one constraint I do not know how to define.

The optimization problem is that I have 12 stocks, and I wish to find an optimum with one of the constraints being that six or more stocks are used in the portfolio.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

(The summation of weights is to be `1` if that makes any difference.)

And is it possible to make IF-statements in the solver?

The last constraint I am unsure of is how to state that only weights of 5% or more are to be considered in the portfolio.

Comment: **What is the parameter being optimized??**

Comment: The summation of weights. (=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather that you have 12 decision variables `w_1, w_2 ,..., w_12` where `w_i` is the weight of stock `i` in the portfolio. Introduce 12 new decision variable, `b_1, b_2, ..., b_12` which are constrained to be binary (0 or 1) -- easily enforceable in the solver. Add a new constraint whereby the sum of these is to be >= 6. You need to ensure both that

```
b_i = 1 <=> w_i > 0
```

And

```
w_i > 0 => w_i >= 0.05
```

Add the following 24 constraints (2 for each stock):

```
0.05 * b_i <= w_i <= b_i
```

The constraints `0.05 * b_i <= w_i` force `w_i >= 0.05` when `b_i = 1`. The constraints `w_i <= b_i` force `b_i = 1` if `w_i > 0`

In a spreadsheet, if your decision variables are in a column you can introduce a new column labeled e.g. `Used?` next to your decision variables to hold the new decision variables and, perhaps another columns to hold the products `0.05 *b_i`.

A final point -- it is probably good to have the min weight `0.05` in a cell somewhere rather than being hard-wired in so that it can be modified.